# Remove duplicate rows from mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table called `urls`

It has the following fields

```
url
title (default null)
content (default null)
```

My table has many duplicate rows.

I would like to remove those duplicates.

For example

```
google.com - Google - search engine
google.com - null - null
google.com - Google - search engine
```

Now I would like to drop the rows where `title = null` plus the duplicate row.

I just want the url to be unique with no duplicate rows.

Can some tell me how?

Comment: Does this table have a primary key field ID ?

Comment: No.. `url` is the primary key

Comment: @Giri, for begin, mark your `url` field as `unique`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the simplest:

```
create tableB like tableA;
INSERT INTO tableB SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tableA WHERE title IS NOT NULL;
DROP tableA;
RENAME tableB TO tableA;
```

Even in a production environment the drop and rename is usually quick enough to be near invisible to any users. Double check to make sure you end up with the appropriate indexes.

Answer (score 0):

you can add url as the unique index.the following query will add the unique index and remove the deuplicates.

```
alter ignore table urls add unique index(url);
```

If you dont want to add unique index, then the alternate is to create a temp table with unique index,copy the data,remove the duplicate and transfer back to your original table.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DELETE FROM urls WHERE title IS NULL 
           OR url IN (SELECT a.URL from urls a, urls b WHERE a.url=b.url);
```